# How to get the URL that loads the XSL page?

Tags: java, url, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm a beginner with XSL. I need to use it with Java. The problem is I do not know how to get the value of the url that loads that XSL.

ex: www.mypage.com/resource.json

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="@content" /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want in the end is that the URL contains .json then display different information, for example if the URL contains .xml

Comment: It sounds like the easiest option is to have a different XSL for each type of input, like transform-xml.xsl, transform-json.xsl, and so on.  Your Java code can easily determine which one to use at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, use `xsl:param` to pass the URI of the XSL or current document.

In XSLT 2.0, the XSLT file URI can be obtained via:

```
base-uri(document(''))
```

In XSLT 2.0, the current document URI can be obtained via:

```
base-uri()
```

Note: URIs do not necessarily exist for the XSLT or input XML because it's possible that these reside only in memory without being associated with a file.